# Oracle SQL how to merge rows with different data into single row

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm incredibly stuck and I have no idea how to proceed.

Say I have this table:

```
ID  Condition_1  Condition_2  Condition_3  Condition_4
--  -----------  -----------  -----------  -----------
 1  X                                                  
 1               X                                     
 1                            X                        
 2  X                                                  
 3                            X                        
 3               X                                     
 4                                         X
```

I want to construct a query that would return just one row per ID. Something like:

```
ID  Condition_1  Condition_2  Condition_3  Condition_4
--  -----------  -----------  -----------  -----------
 1  X            X            X                        
 2  X                                                  
 3               X            X                        
 4                                         X
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, than this should do:

```
select id, max(condition_1) as condition_1, max(condition_2) as condition_2, .....
from   your_table
group  by id
order  by id    -- if needed
```

However, I have a suspicion that what you showed us is not your raw data, but rather, the intermediate result (or "as far as you were able to go without help") in the solution to a bigger problem. If so, you might get better help sharing the overall problem with us. We can probably show you how to do everything in fewer steps; you shouldn't have to get the result in the form you show it as "input", only to do further processing to get the result you **really** want.

Comment: You are correct @mathguy, once I have a bit more time I will post the bigger problem. Thank you, again.